# Proving statement about critical and uniquely colorable graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. A graph $G$ is called critical, if $\chi(G) > \chi(G - v)$ for all $v \in V$. Furthermore I use the definition of unique coloring that is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniquely_colorable_graph. I read that the following is supposed to be true: If $G$ is a critical graph that is uniquely colorable, then $G$ has to be complete. I know that the other implication is certainly true, however, I can't seem to show why this implication is supposed to be true. Perhaps the following is possible.

Assume that $G$ is not complete and not critical. Furthermore let $c:V \to \{1,..,k\}$ be a minimal coloring of $G$. Since $G$ is not complete, there are distinct $v_1,v_2 \in V$ such that $\{v_1,v_2\} \notin E$. If $k=1$, $G$ can't have edges (is there a contradiction?). If $k>1$, we either have $(1)$ $c(v_1) = c(v_2)$ or $(2)$ $c(v_1) \neq c(v_2)$.

In case $(1)$, we can define another coloring $c':V \to \{1,...,k\}$ by $c'(v)=c(v)$ for all vertices $v$ that are not $v_1$. Since $k>1$ there has to be a $u \in V$ such that $c(u) \neq c(v_1).$ Then define $c'(v_1)=c(u)$ (however, u might be in an edge with $v_1$, so this should not work without further thought). We obtain a coloring $c':V \to \{1,...,k\}.$

In case $(2)$, we can again define another coloring $c':V \to \{1,...,k\}$ by $c'(v)=c(v)$ for all $v \in V$ except for $v_1,v_2$, where we define $c'(v_1)=c'(v_2)$. This has to also be a $k$-coloring, since otherwise $G$ would be critical. Since there are some gaps and probably errors in my idea, I don't think that this is a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can reason in the following way. Suppose that $G$ is non-complete and critical. Let $c$ be a coloring of $G$ with $\chi(G)$ colors. Since $G$ is not complete, its chromatic number is less than the number of vertices (why?). It follows that we can find a pair of vertices $v_1,v_2$ with $c(v_1) = c(v_2)$. Now $G - {v_1}$ can be colored with $\chi(G) - 1$ colors. Let $c'$ be such a coloring and extend it to a coloring of $G$ by letting $c'(v_1)$ be the unused color. Now $c'(v_1) \neq c'(v_2)$, so $c'$ cannot be obtained from $c$ by permuting the colors. This shows that $G$ is not uniquely colorable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand you correctly, you are using not C and A implies B to prove A and B implies C, right? Why is this a valid way to prove this?

Comment: That's not the logic here. This proves "if critical and non-complete, then *not* uniquely colorable". In other words, it's impossible to have "critical, non-complete, and uniquely colorable". So if something is critical and uniquely colorable, it can't also be non-complete: it must be complete. That's what we wanted. (To prove A and B implies C, we prove that A and not(C) implies not(B).)

Comment: Also, it's interesting to observe that critical and not complete graphs can be uniquely colorable under a more flexible definition: one that includes graph automorphisms. For example, the $5$-cycle is $3$-critical. All colorings of it "look the same" in that we can start at a vertex and go around the cycle to see an A-B-A-B-C pattern. But they are not all equivalent up to permuting colors, because color permutations don't affect which vertex gets the unique color.